# Implicações em usar inner join e left join em um mesmo select

Tags: sql-server, join

Tenho alguns *stored procedures* em um banco SQL Server 2008 R2, esses *stored procedures* possuem vários *joins*, em alguns casos utilizei no mesmo *select*, *inner join* e *left join*, por exemplo:

```
Tabela Pessoa
| IDPessoa | Nome  |
|    1     | João  |
|    2     | Maria |
|    3     | José  |

Tabela Nascimento
| IDData | IDPessoa | DataNascimento |
|   1    |    1     |   01/01/2000   |     
|   2    |    2     |   10/05/2001   |
|   3    |    3     |   25/09/2009   |

Tabela Telefone
| IDTelefone | IDPessoa | IDTipo |  Numero   |
|      1     |     1    |    1   | 1523-4565 |
|      2     |     3    |    5¹  | 8481-9847 |
¹ esse valor não existe na tabela TipoTelefone.

Tabela TipoTelefone
| IDTipo |     Tipo    |
|    1   | Comercial   |
|    2   | Residencial |
```

```
SELECT 
    Nome, 
    DataNascimento, 
    Numero, 
    Tipo 
FROM 
    Pessoa
    INNER JOIN Nascimento ON (Pessoa.IDPessoa = Nascimento.IDPessoa)
    LEFT JOIN Telefone ON (Pessoa.IDPessoa = Telefone.IDPessoa)
    LEFT JOIN TipoTelefone ON (Telefone.IDTipo = TipoTelefone.IDTipo)
```

> **Nota:** as tabelas e o *select* acima foram só para exemplificar os três casos:
>
> 1. registros que sempre existirão em ambas tabelas (Pessoa x Nascimento)
> 2. registros que podem não existir em uma das tabelas (Pessoa x Telefone); e
> 3. registros que dependem de outra tabela que está no *join* (Telefone x TipoTelefone)

Dei uma olhada na pergunta [Qual é a diferença entre inner join e outer join?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/) que explica detalhadamente os *joins*, porém ela não fala sobre utilizar mais de um tipo de *join* em um *select*.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum problema/implicação de utilizar os *joins* exemplificados acima e se existe algum ponto de atenção quando se utiliza essa abordagem.

Comment: não vejo problema algum, pois já vi muitas consultas em sistemas de prefeituras que usavam muito, mas muitos joins e muitos unions também, acho que tudo depende da lógica da tua consulta, mas usar unions deixa a consulta com menos performance, eu sempre procuro evitar o uso de union, só em ultimo caso onde não consigo resolver de outras formas.

Comment: +1 pela pesquisa prévia e boa explicação/formatação da pergunta, ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe uma ordem lógica a seguir.

Para o seu modelo, é possível mudar a ordem de seus joins sem problema nenhum. Isso porque todos eles estão baseados em uma tabela principal que sempre estará presente para realizar suas comparações (tabela Pessoa).

Mas nem sempre pode ser o caso.
Imagine um sistema com as tabelas abaixo:

```
  tb_pessoa           tb_pessoa_juridica  tb_pessoa_usuario
  ------------------  ------------------  ------------------------
  id_pessoa           id_pessoa           id_pessoa
  dc_apelido          dc_razao_social     dc_usuario_login
  dc_email            dc_cnpj             dc_senha
```

Nem todas as pessoas possuem acesso ao sistema, ou seja, nem todas possuem um cadastro na `tb_pessoa_usuario`. Também nem todas são pessoas jurídicas, somente as que são possuem cadastro na `tb_pessoa_juridica`.

Imagine um cenário de uma listagem em que o seu cliente quer saber quem são todas as pessoas com acesso ao sistema (ou seja, os com cadastro de usuário). Também, todos as pessoas jurídicas deverão aparecer, constando o usuário delas se houver. Se a pessoa jurídica não possuir um usuário, ele quer que elas apareçam na listagem para que ele possa cadastrar um usuário para elas.

Veja o caso de um `SELECT` onde a ordem importa:

```
     SELECT 
           p.id_pessoa
          ,p.dc_apelido
          ,p.dc_email
          ,u.dc_usuario_login
          ,j.dc_razao_social
     FROM
          tb_pessoa p                   -- (1)traz todas as pessoas
     LEFT JOIN
          tb_pessoa_juridica j ON       -- (2)junta informações da jurídica se houver
             p.id_pessoa = j.id_pessoa
     INNER JOIN                         -- (3)erro: agora pega somente as que tem usuário
          tb_pessoa_usuario u ON
             p.id_pessoa = u.id_pessoa
```

O `INNER JOIN` no ponto (3) está destruindo o seu `LEFT JOIN` no ponto (2). Isto porque você não quer todas as informações da tabela inicial, você quer uma associação `INNER` entre `tb_pessoa` e `tb_pessoa_usuario`. Portanto não dá para fazer um `LEFT JOIN`, você irá pegar pessoas que não são usuários.

A correção seria trocar a ordem da (2) para a (3):

```
     SELECT 
           p.id_pessoa
          ,p.dc_apelido
          ,p.dc_email
          ,u.dc_usuario_login
          ,j.dc_razao_social
     FROM
          tb_pessoa p                   -- (1)traz todas as pessoas
     INNER JOIN                         -- (2)pega somente as que tem usuário
          tb_pessoa_usuario u ON
             p.id_pessoa = u.id_pessoa
     LEFT JOIN
          tb_pessoa_juridica j ON       -- (3)junta informações da jurídica se houver
             p.id_pessoa = j.id_pessoa
```

Neste caso, estamos primeiro pegando informações que são obrigatórias e depois juntando com informações que talvez devem aparecer.

Não existe uma regra para seguir, somente a lógica. Mas eu gosto de tomar algumas medidas de precaução em minhas construções:

1. Sempre utilize primeiro `INNER JOIN`s quando houver. Se houver `OUTER JOIN`s, coloque-os depois
2. `INNER JOINS` são calculados mais rápidos que os `OUTER JOIN`s, dessa forma sua consulta fica mais rápida quando eles começam primeiro.
3. Procure associar seus `JOIN`s (todos eles, `INNER` e `OUTER`) com chaves primárias (PK) de uma tabela com as chaves estrangeiras (FK) das outras. Não coloque um filtro no `ON`, utilize filtros no `WHERE`. As informações são ligadas mais rápidas com chaves. Não misture associação (chaves) com filtros!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
4. Estude o `CROSS APPLY` se você estiver usando bancos Microsoft SQL Server! Ele pode ser muito melhor que os `INNER JOIN`s em várias situações! Isto tem muito a ver na ordem como o banco de dados seleciona os dados e depois os filtra.

Comment: então o que realmente será considerado é a ordem em que os *joins* são colocados? Se a lógica estiver correta não terei problemas?

Comment: @MateusAlexandre exatamente!